# Pass prediction method as function argument

Tags: python, scikit-learn, arguments, predict

I'd like to specify which prediction method to use via function argument. Something like:

```
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression

def Process(data_y_train, data_x_train, data_x_test, 
            model=LinearRegression, predict_method=predict):
  model_fit = model().fit(data_x_train, data_y_train)
  predicted_values = model_fit.predict_method(data_x_test)
  return predicted_values
```

Passing the model function via arugment `model` (e.g., LinearRegression, LogisticRegression) works well, but I'm having trouble passing the predict method (e.g., predict, predict_proba) via argument `predict_method`.

When I specify `predict_method=predict`, I get an error of 'name 'predict' is not defined'; if I specify `predict_method=LinearRegression.predict`, I get an error saying ''LinearRegression' object has no attribute 'predict_function''.

Per [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3061/calling-a-function-of-a-module-by-using-its-name-a-string), I also tried

```
import sklearn.linear_model.LinearRegression

def Process(data_y_train, data_x_train, data_x_test, 
            model_module='sklearn.linear_model.LinearRegression',
            model=LinearRegression, predict_method='predict'):
  model_fit = model().fit(data_x_train, data_y_train)
  predict_call = getattr(__import__(model_module), predict_method)
  predicted_values = model_fit.predict_call(data_x_test)
  return predicted_values
```

But here I get an error: No module named LinearRegression.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Can you edit in the expected output and try to make this a bit more minimal? (see how to make a [mcve])

Answer (score 1):

I notice that in your code, you're not using the `predict_method` parameter that you passed in anywhere in your code, so I don't think what you have written is what you were trying to do.

Currently, in your code, you are storing the output of the function `model().fit(data_x_train, data_y_train)` in the variable `model_fit` and then calling the `predict_method` attribute of that variable. If the above still doesn't work, that must be where the error is coming from, then.

I suspect what you *want* to do is the following:

```
def Process(data_y_train, data_x_train, data_x_test,
            model=LinearRegression, predict_method=LinearRegression.predict):
    model_instance = model() # create an instance of the class stored in the variable 'model'
    model_instance.fit(data_x_train, data_y_train) # run the function 'fit' belonging to that instance
    predicted_values = predict_method(model_instance,data_x_test) # run the method stored in the variable 'predict_method' - you have to pass the instance the method belongs to in the first parameter
    return predicted_values
```

Some more information:

- `LinearRegression` is a *class*. It defines a bunch of methods, etc.
- To create an *instance* of that class, you must do something like `inst = LinearRegression()`. The variable `inst` is now an instance of the class `LinearRegression`
- `LinearRegression.predict` is an example of an *instance method*. This means it needs an instance to run (or can be thought of as to 'operate on' in this case)
- I can therefore call `inst.predict(x,y,z)` but not `LinearRegression.predict(x,y,z)` directly.
- If you want to call `LinearRegression.predict`, you have to pass in the instance in the first argument: `LinearRegression.predict(inst,x,y,z)`

Regarding what you tried afterwards: calling a function from a string holding the function's name is not necessary in this situation and only increases the overhead, so it's probably not the correct way to go here :)

Hope this helps.

Comment: I did use `LinearRegression.predict` and just double checked with `predict_method=LogisticRegression.predict_proba`, I'm getting a similar error ''LogisticRegression' object has no attribute 'predict_method''. I'm using `sklearn` 0.20.0. Thanks Abhinav!